# What does it mean that an SMB-server explicitly supports Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, smb

What does it mean that an SMB-server explicitly supports Time Machine? E.g., on my NAS I can enable SMB and then I can also enable support for Time Machine. OTOH, there are routers that supports filesharing via SMB but does **not** support Time Machine.

What does this mean? Does Time Machine require an SMB-server to support some extension of the SMB protocol (or something like that) that not all SMB servers includes?

Comment: Yes to the "something like that". Even macOS as TM destination needs to have TM serving explicitly enabled. Hopefully someone has a full explanation for what is required.

Comment: This page <https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_Samba_to_Work_Better_with_Mac_OS_X> talks about enabling extensions added in Samba 4.8 to support Timemachine

Comment: And vfs_fruit <https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_fruit.8.html> talks about adding support for Info and Resource streams.